# Heroku not finding procfile - Flask-SocketIO

Tags: python, heroku, gunicorn, flask-socketio

I am trying to deploy a flask-socketio project to the web, but the build isn't noticing the web dyno. I made a file called `Procfile`, without an extension. Inside procfile it has

```
web:gunicorn manage:app
```

Should I change manage to manage.py? Why does the build look like

```
-----> Python app detected
-----> Installing requirements with pip
-----> Discovering process types
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 46.1M
-----> Launching...
       Released v32
       https://use-chats.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

One time it said it had found a web dyno, but now it isn't.

Comment: Is gunicorn is in your requirements.txt?

Comment: Yes, it is in requirements.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the Procfile requires a space between the `<process_type>:` and the command to run:

```
web: gunicorn manage:app
```

A useful resource:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-gunicorn